How can I decrease the space between my points on y-axis in geom_dotplot in R?
I'm trying to make a dotplot with antibody titers (y-axis) ranging from 1:20 to 1:640 by site (x-axis) and I can't reduce the space between the points on the y-axis.
I tried applying log2 to the scale, but it didn't work. Since I'm just starting out with R, I'd like to know if anyone could help me.
This is part of the data I'm working with:
structure(list(AMOSTRA = c("A11", "A17", "A19", "A20", "A21", 
"A23", "A24", "A27", "A30", "A32", "A33", "A35", "A77", "A91", 
"A111", "A193", "A200", "A206", "A216", "A291", "A292", "A304", 
"A324", "A336", "A339", "A340", "A351", "A353", "A354", "A372", 
"A375", "A385", "A389", "A392", "A396", "H059", "H074", "H081", 
"H104", "H107", "H109", "H114", "H134", "H163", "H166", "H186", 
"H208", "H221", "H222", "H256"), NEUTRALIZAÇÃO = c("Neutralizante", 
"Neutralizante", "Neutralizante", "Neutralizante", "Neutralizante", 
"Neutralizante", "Neutralizante", "Neutralizante", "Neutralizante", 
"Neutralizante", "Neutralizante", "Neutralizante", "Neutralizante", 
"Neutralizante", "Neutralizante", "Neutralizante", "Neutralizante", 
"Neutralizante", "Neutralizante", "Neutralizante", "Neutralizante", 
"Neutralizante", "Neutralizante", "Neutralizante", "Neutralizante", 
"Neutralizante", "Neutralizante", "Neutralizante", "Neutralizante", 
"Neutralizante", "Neutralizante", "Neutralizante", "Neutralizante", 
"Neutralizante", "Neutralizante", "Neutralizante", "Neutralizante", 
"Neutralizante", "Neutralizante", "Neutralizante", "Neutralizante", 
"Neutralizante", "Neutralizante", "Não neutralizante", "Não neutralizante", 
"Não neutralizante", "Neutralizante", "Neutralizante", "Não neutralizante", 
"Neutralizante"), TITULO = c(80, 40, 640, 640, 40, 160, 160, 
160, 80, 20, 640, 160, 320, 640, 320, 320, 640, 640, 640, 40, 
160, 320, 640, 640, 80, 320, 640, 160, 80, 160, 320, 640, 320, 
320, 640, 640, 640, 640, 640, 160, 160, 320, 320, 80, 80, 40, 
160, 640, 80, 640), LOCAL = c("Coari", "Coari", "Coari", "Coari", 
"Coari", "Coari", "Coari", "Coari", "Coari", "Coari", "Coari", 
"Coari", "Coari", "Coari", "Coari", "Coari", "Coari", "Coari", 
"Coari", "Coari", "Coari", "Coari", "Coari", "Coari", "Coari", 
"Coari", "Coari", "Coari", "Coari", "Coari", "Coari", "Coari", 
"Coari", "Coari", "Coari", "Manaus", "Manaus", "Manaus", "Manaus", 
"Manaus", "Manaus", "Manaus", "Manaus", "Manaus", "Manaus", "Manaus", 
"Manaus", "Manaus", "Manaus", "Manaus"), ROUND = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), na.action = structure(c(`2` = 2L, 
`4` = 4L, `6` = 6L, `8` = 8L, `10` = 10L, `12` = 12L, `14` = 14L, 
`16` = 16L, `18` = 18L, `20` = 20L, `22` = 22L, `24` = 24L, `26` = 26L, 
`28` = 28L, `30` = 30L, `32` = 32L, `34` = 34L, `36` = 36L, `38` = 38L, 
`40` = 40L, `42` = 42L, `44` = 44L, `46` = 46L, `48` = 48L, `50` = 50L, 
`52` = 52L, `54` = 54L, `56` = 56L, `58` = 58L, `60` = 60L, `62` = 62L, 
`64` = 64L, `66` = 66L, `68` = 68L), class = "omit"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

This is the code I'm using:
data_summary_1= function(y) {
  data.frame(
    y = median(y),              
    ymin = quantile(y, 0.25),
    ymax = quantile(y, 0.75) 
  )
}

figure_3_median = ggplot(dados, aes(x = LOCAL, y = TITULO, fill = LOCAL)) + 
     geom_dotplot(binaxis = 'y', stackdir = 'center', stackratio = 1.0, dotsize = 0.8) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#FAD510","#A16928")) +
    stat_summary(fun.data = data_summary_1, geom = "pointrange", color = 'black') +
       scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log2', breaks = c(40,160,640), labels = c("40","160","640")) +
     theme_classic()
figure_3_median

This is the plot that is being generated:
I want to reduce the space between the points on the y-axis or stack the points like this image: DotPlot or similar to this: Dotplot2

It's good etiquette (and will help you get useful answers) if you can include some sample data. Otherwise we can't run your code and will need to make up data of our own (which might or might not reproduce the issue you're seeing) to test potential solutions.

Can you run dput(head(dados, 20)) and paste the output into your question?

Sorry, I'm not used to using these forums. I will run the code and put the data in my question. Sorry for the inconvenience.

I added the data in the question. I ran dput(head(data, 50)) for a better representation of the data.

The data you're comparing to has a distribution of many y values, where geom_dotplot can bin a continuous distribution into a discrete one. Your data has only 6 y values, which is why it looks like that. You could use something like library(dplyr); ggplot(dados |> mutate(TITULO = TITULO * rnorm(n(), 1, 0.1)), ... to add some noise to your data to make it more like those, but that might just be misleading.

Bom dia Gabriel. As Jon pointed out, the "spread" along the y-axis is a characteristic of your data. Note: in the end, a geom_dotplot() is another form of a histogram. If you want to "stash" the spread, you can use a transformation (e.g. as proposed by Jon). Alternatively, you can also "recode" each value to make it a categorical value. This way, the "steps" (along the y-axis) would have only an ordering (of unit 1 ~ think next integer). While the spread will be gone, the y-offset has then no numerical meaning. If the numerical values are important, you could overwrite the y-axis labels.

Gabriel!
I did some tests here with a similar dataset and by inserting  "ylim()" did the trick.
Try something like:
figure_3_median = ggplot(dados, aes(x = LOCAL, y = TITULO, fill = LOCAL)) + 
 geom_dotplot(binaxis = 'y', stackdir = 'center', stackratio = 1.0, dotsize = 0.8) +
scale_fill_manual(values = c("#FAD510","#A16928")) +
stat_summary(fun.data = data_summary_1, geom = "pointrange", color = 'black') +
   scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log2', breaks = c(40,160,640), labels = c("40","160","640")) + ylim(0,800)+
 theme_classic()

figure_3_median
Forte abraço!!

Pedro, thank you very much for your willingness to help.
But I tried it here and it didn't work exactly as I want. I think it's probably due to the distribution of my data.
Valeu pela ajuda!!

I don't see how this is responsive to the question. Unless I'm mistaken, adjusting ylim is only going to change the range of data that is displayed, and won't do anything to "fuzz" the discrete y values into a more continuous distribution. https://r4ds.had.co.nz/graphics-for-communication.html#zooming

Gabriel, can you show us a picture of a graph similar to what you are looking for?
